# Calculate how many touch points the customer had in X months

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem. I want to calculate from a date for example `2022-06-01` how many touches the customer with the `customerId == 1` had in the last `6 months`. He had two touches `2022-05-25` and `2022-05-20`. I have now calculated the date up to which the data should be taken into account. However, I don't know how to group the customer and say the date you have is up to `count_from_date` how many touches the customer has had.

Dataframe

```
  customerId    fromDate
0           1  2022-06-01
1           1  2022-05-25
2           1  2022-05-25
3           1  2022-05-20
4           1  2021-09-05
5           2  2022-06-02
6           3  2021-03-01
7           3  2021-02-01
```

```py
import pandas as pd


d = {'customerId': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3],
     'fromDate': ["2022-06-01", "2022-05-25", "2022-05-25", "2022-05-20", "2021-09-05",
                  "2022-06-02", "2021-03-01", "2021-02-01"]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)

from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
def find_last_date(date):
  six_months = date + relativedelta(months=-6)
  return six_months

df['fromDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fromDate'], errors='coerce')
df['count_from_date'] = df['fromDate'].apply(lambda x: find_last_date(x))
print(df)
```

What I have

```py
   customerId   fromDate count_from_date
0           1 2022-06-01      2021-12-01
1           1 2022-05-25      2021-11-25
2           1 2022-05-25      2021-11-25
3           1 2022-05-20      2021-11-20
4           1 2021-09-05      2021-03-05
5           2 2022-06-02      2021-12-02
6           3 2021-03-01      2020-09-01
7           3 2021-02-01      2020-08-01
```

What I want

```py
   customerId   fromDate count_from_date  occur_last_6_months
0           1 2022-06-01      2021-12-01  3   # 2022-05-25, 2022-05-20, 2022-05-20 = 3
1           1 2022-05-25      2021-11-25  1   # 2022-05-20 = 1
2           1 2022-05-25      2021-11-25  1   # 2022-05-20 = 1
3           1 2022-05-20      2021-11-20  0   # No in the last 6 months
4           1 2021-09-05      2021-03-05  0   # No in the last 6 months
5           2 2022-06-02      2021-12-02  0   # No in the last 6 months
6           3 2021-03-01      2020-09-01  1   # 2021-02-01 = 1
7           3 2021-02-01      2020-08-01  0   # No in the last 6 months
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try groupby `customerId` and loop through the rows in subgroup to count number of `fromDate` between `fromDate` and `count_from_date`

```py
def count(g):
    m = pd.concat([g['fromDate'].between(d1, d2, 'neither')
                   for d1, d2 in zip(g['count_from_date'], g['fromDate'])], axis=1)
    g = g.assign(occur_last_6_months=m.sum().tolist())
    return g

out = df.groupby('customerId').apply(count)
```

```
print(out)

   customerId   fromDate count_from_date  occur_last_6_months
0           1 2022-06-01      2021-12-01                    3
1           1 2022-05-25      2021-11-25                    1
2           1 2022-05-25      2021-11-25                    1
3           1 2022-05-20      2021-11-20                    0
4           1 2021-09-05      2021-03-05                    0
5           2 2022-06-02      2021-12-02                    0
6           3 2021-03-01      2020-09-01                    1
7           3 2021-02-01      2020-08-01                    0
```

Comment: Please see my edit. I had a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

For this problem, the challenge for a *performant* solution is to manipulate the data as to have an appropriate structure to run `rolling` window operations on it.

First of all, we need to avoid having duplicate indices. In your case, this means aggregating multiple touch points in a single day:

```
>>> df = df.groupby(['customerId', 'fromDate'], as_index=False).count() 

   customerId   fromDate  count_from_date
0           1 2021-09-05                1
1           1 2022-05-20                1
2           1 2022-05-25                2
3           1 2022-06-01                1
4           2 2022-06-02                1
5           3 2021-02-01                1
6           3 2021-03-01                1
```

Now, we can set the index to `fromDate`, sort it and groupby `customerId` as to be able to use `rolling` windows. I here use a `180D` rolling window (6 months):

```
>>> roll_df = df.set_index(['fromDate'])
                .sort_index()
                .groupby('customerId')
                .apply(lambda s: s['count_from_date'].rolling('180D').sum())
```

The `sort_index` step is important to ensure your data is monotonically increasing.

However, this also counts the touch on the day itself, which seems not what you want, so we remove 1 from the result:

```
>>> roll_df - 1

customerId  fromDate  
1           2021-09-05    0.0
            2022-05-20    0.0
            2022-05-25    2.0
            2022-06-01    3.0
2           2022-06-02    0.0
3           2021-02-01    0.0
            2021-03-01    1.0
Name: count_from_date, dtype: float64
```

Finally, we divide by the initial counts to get back to the original structure:

```
 >>> roll_df / df.set_index(['customerId', 'fromDate'])['count_from_date']
```

```
  customerId   fromDate  count_from_date
0           1 2021-09-05              0.0
1           1 2022-05-20              0.0
2           1 2022-05-25              1.0
3           1 2022-06-01              3.0
4           2 2022-06-02              0.0
5           3 2021-02-01              0.0
6           3 2021-03-01              1.0
```

You can always `.reset_index()` at the end.

---

The one liner solution is

```
(df.set_index(['fromDate'])
   .sort_index()
   .groupby('customerId')
   .apply(lambda s: s['count_from_date'].rolling('180D').sum())
   - 1) / df.set_index(['customerId', 'fromDate'])['count_from_date']
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate it. If I am running the `one liner solution` I got `KeyError: 'count_from_date'` or `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`.Depending on whether I have the column `count_from_date` in or no. Did I miss something ?

Comment: sorry. the `count_from_date` column in my example is that resulting column with the counts for each date. Check in your dataframe what is the corresponding name, and use that name instead of `count_from_date` in your code. In other words, see the resulting name of `df.groupby(['customerId', 'fromDate'], as_index=False).count()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer again! And sorry, however I have run it with the line `df.groupby(['customerId', 'fromDate'], as_index=False).count()` and it still comes up with an error. Could you please show me what you mean exactly? Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer?

Comment: These line `df = df.groupby(['customerId', 'fromDate'], as_index=False).count() ` does not delivery me the same output as yours